# Python: How to unpack dictionary keys as separate items rather than one item

Tags: python, dictionary, prettytable

When I run:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable as PTable

accounts = {
    'user1': 'pass1',
    'user2': 'pass2'
}

table = PTable(['Day', [*accounts.keys()]])  #  creates empty table with headings
print(table)
```

My table looks like this:

```
+-----+--------------------+
| Day | ['user1', 'user2'] |
+-----+--------------------+
+-----+--------------------+
```

You can see that 'user1' and 'user2' are in the same column. How can I make it so that they are in separate columns?

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use the Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet button unless your code is actually Javascript, HTML, or CSS.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't know there was another button

Comment: There isn't another button, but no other languages have built in snippet support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *did* unpack them as separate items... of the wrong list. If you wanted to unpack them into the same list as `'Day'`, don't write a nested list:

```
['Day', *accounts.keys()]
```

Comment: @Redjman Glad its fixed, be sure to accept it is the correct answer!